# modifying a nested dict while iterating

Tags: python, python-2.7

Which manipulations are allowed when iterating over a dict?

> Using iteritems() while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise    a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries.
>   (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems)

So is it OK to change an exisiting value even if this changes the size of the dict?
For example when I iterate over the keys [1, 2] is ok to

- change the value of [1][11][111]["data1"] to "one".
- completely remove [1][11]?
- add [1]["eleven"] = { ... }

If this is not allowed, what would be the best practice? Do I really have to store the path to the value I want to manipulate and do the manipulation in a copy of the dict? Are there other mapping types I could use, ElementTree for example?

```
{
  1: {
    11: {
      111: {
        "data1": 1,
        "data2": 2
      }
    }
  },
  2: {
    22: {
      222: {
        "data1": 11,
        "data2": 22
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the operations you've described even touch the outer dict. They're completely fine to do.

If you did something like

```
for key in outer_dict:
    outer_dict[key] = something_different
```

that *would* touch the outer dict, but it would still be fine. As long as you're not inserting or removing keys in the dict you're iterating over, you won't trigger a rehashing.